# $.deferred does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

on some button's click event I'm calling function a() which contains below mentioned Ajax call, in the success I'm using `$.Deferred`. It works perfectly fine on very first click of the button but when I click a button second, third, fourth... or  nth time it does not work as expected (It does not go inside of confirmation function at all). what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "some url",
            data: {
                parameters
            },
            success: function (result) {
                 //result is an Array object. for example **result:Array[3]**, further expand result will be like this **result[0]:Array[19], result[1]:Array[39], result[2]:Array[15]**
                var defer = $.Deferred();

                function confirmation(result) {
                    if (result.length > 1) {

                $('#field' + questionID).append('<div id=dialog></div>');
                $("#dialog").append('<div id=grid></div>');

                $("#dialog").kendoDialog({
                    modal: true,
                    visible: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    closable: false,
                    title: "Please Select One Submission",
                    maxWidth: 500,
                    //maxHeight:300,
                    animation: {
                        open: {
                            effects: "slideIn:down fadeIn",
                            duration: 500
                        },
                        close: {
                            effects: "slide:up fadeOut",
                            duration: 500
                        }
                    },
                    actions: [
                        { text: 'OK', primary: true, action: onOK }
                    ]
                });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                       data: result,
                        schema: {
                            data: function (result) {
                                return $.map(result, function (item) {
                                    return $.map(item, function (innerData) {
                                        for (var i = 0; i < displayFields.length; i++) {
                                            if (displayFields[i] == innerData.FieldIDString) {
                                                return {
                                                    EntryGroupID: innerData.EntryGroupID,
                                                    FieldTextString: innerData.FieldTextString,
                                                    EntryValue: innerData.EntryValue
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                });
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 2,
                        group: { field: "EntryGroupID" }                           
                    },
                    filterable: {
                        mode: "row"
                    },
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                    },
                    noRecords: {
                        template: "No records to display"
                    },
                    groupable:false,
                    //scrollable: true,
                    selectable: true,
                    columns: [{
                        field: "EntryGroupID",
                        title: "Submissions",
                        filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        field: "FieldTextString",
                        title: "Questions",
                        filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        field: "EntryValue",
                        title: "Answers",
                        filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains"
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                });

                var wnd = $("#dialog").data("kendoDialog");
                wnd.wrapper.find('.k-dialog-title').css('background', CIMSFields.backgroundColour).css('color', CIMSFields.textColour).css('width','100%').css('text-align','center');
                wnd.open().center(true);

                //in this function i'm waiting for user response which they will choose one array object based on this value **Confirmation** function will get the data.
                function onOK(e) {
                    var data = [];
                    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                    if (selectedItem != null) {
                        $.map(result, function (item) {
                            if (selectedItem.EntryGroupID == item[0].EntryGroupID) {
                                data.push(item);
                                defer.resolve(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        defer.resolve(data);
                    }
                    wnd.close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                defer.resolve(result);
            }
            return defer.promise();
       }        
       alert(defer.state());        
       confirmation(result).then(function (data) {
          //it never reach here except first time
             alert(defer.state());                        
             alert(data);// data is the user selected value from the grid.                        
          })
      }
});
```

Comment: Did you check to see if you are getting an error on your Ajax call on the nth times?  Add an error handler to your ajax call to see.  Except for the deferred anti-pattern (creating a new deferred when `$.ajax()` already returns one, I don't see anything in the code you show that would cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: FYI, `$.ajax()` already returns a promise so you can do `$.ajax().then(...).then(...)`.

Comment: Why do you use `result.length > 1`, then `!data.empty`? What is expected result of `!data.empty`? Is `data` an array?

Comment: What is purpose of `if..else` where `.resolve()` is called at each block?

Comment: yes data is an object of an array. for example data[0]->Array[39]. i'm checking the length of result cause if there is more then one array object, result will populate in the grid otherwise it simply returns an object to confirmation function where I'm  checking if data is not empty. hope that make sense to you.

Comment: the defer seems... not useful in your situation. It's usually used for asynchronous actions that don't support promises, but you're not doing anything asynchronous with it.

Comment: I have explained situation with my actual code. I hope my question make sense now. In `Confirmation` function i'm waiting for user response which `Array object` they would like to see. and i'm giving that opportunity to user in the `kendo grid` to select a particular value, based on their answer i'm trying to display that value in `confirmation` function.

Comment: my result is an `Array` object `if (Array>1)` then allow user to select one array object else just pass that result to `confirmation` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[found my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033008/jquery-waiting-for-user-input)

basically my need was I have to wait for user response in the function before proceeding further. Thank you all who took time to respond my question. I appreciate your time and effort. Most importantly I'm not using `deferred` at all now.

Answer (score 0):

If `result` is an array, `.empty` is not an `Array` property or method. `$.Deferred()` is not necessary, `$.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object.

You can check `.length` of expected array, or property of expected object at `.then()` chained to `a()` call. Also, chain `.fail()` to log and handle errors that could possibly occur.

```
function a(/* parameters */) {
  // note, we are `return` ing `jQuery.ajax()` call,
  // which returns a jQuery promise object
  return $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "some url", data: {parameters}})

}

a()
.then(function(result, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  console.log(result.length, jqxhr.state());
  if (result.hasOwnProperty("empty")) { console.log(result.empty); }
  else { console.log("result does not have property \"empty\""); };
})
// log, handle errors here
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown, jqxhr.state());
});
```

Comment: you are right about `.empty`. i'll try out your solution and let you know. thank you for the response.

Comment: I've edited my question please take a look. might help you to understand behavior it causing that I've described on the top.