# Javascript - Waiting for user input (callbacks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking at other questions trying to get my head around callbacks but I just can't make sense of it enough to use in my context. I'm writing a text based game which uses purely text input. When needed, I want the game to ask a question with a varying amount of answers and then wait until a valid response is given. Below is an example that doesn't work but explains what I'm trying to do. Can anyone provide me with any guidance? Thanks.

```js
//main code

pEQUIP = ["foo", "foo", "foo"];
exItem = "ball";

function prompt(numPrompts, callback) {
  //waits until user types a number <= numPrompts and presses enter, then returns the valid result entered
}

$('#gametext').append("<p>" + "What slot would you like to use to hold this item?" + "</p>");
//where a function would be stopping the code until a valid answer is given
if (prompt == "1") {
  pEQUIP[0] = exItem;
} else if (prompt == "2") {
  pEQUIP[1] = exItem;
} else if (prompt == "3") {
  pEQUIP[2] = exItem;
}

//Just a quick n dirty way of testing it worked below:
$('#gametext').append("<p>" + pEQUIP[0] + pEQUIP[1] + pEQUIP[2] + "</p>");


//parses user info unsure if this could be used or would have to be copied
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(key) {
    if (key.which === 13 && $('#userinput').is(':focus')) {
      var value = $('#userinput').val().toLowerCase();
      $('#userinput').val("");
      //playerInput(value); Is usually here, would lead to
      //a switch which parses commands typed by the user.
      //Unsure if it can be used for this problem as pausing
      //the code I think would stop the switch?
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="gametext"></div>
  <input id="userinput">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you're thinking of functions incorrectly.

Functions are:

- A series of steps that may return data when they're invoked. You
  invoke a function by passing arguments to the function name, even if
  the arguments are nothing `()` - a.e. `alert(string)` or `myFunction()`
- Not comparable to anything but themselves. In your code you have `prompt == "1"` this isn't going to work. `prompt` is a function name and it isn't invoked so you are literally comparing the function itself to the string "1".
- Able to return data when invoked. That data can be compared.

Note: Also, very importantly, `prompt` is the name of a default function(like `alert` or `console`) and you shouldn't overwrite it. It isn't considered a **reserved** keyword by the language but altering it will cause havok if any other library you're using, or any other programmer doesn't know it's been overwritten, and tries to invoke it.

```js
prompt("this is a normal prompt");
```

Furthermore you  have the document setup to check the value of the text box itself on `keypress`. You should *probably* change this to an event listener on the text box, but there isn't any reason to continuously loop a function beyond this while waiting for the box to match some predefined input.

The Flow is this:

- type in the box
- hit enter
- check value
- if value is *1* or *2* or *3* or *any other acceptable answer* do *something*

If that's all you need currently then you do not need to work so hard for the functionality when a single event listener could do the trick:

```
$("#input_box").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    let value = $("#input_box").val();
    if(value === "1" || value === "2" || value === "3") {
        //do whatever
    }
  }
});
```

```js
$("#input_box").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    let value = $("#input_box").val();
    if(value === "1" || value === "2" || value === "3") {
        console.log("accepted");
    }
    $("#input_box").val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input_box">
```

Comment: Thank you! And I'm sorry, I should have put more thought into my example. I put a function in there as I had seen it used [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033008/jquery-waiting-for-user-input) and I thought I'd need one somewhere. The "prompt" thing was just meant to be a placeholder of some kind, though I was actually unaware that it was a reserved keyword. Anyway, your solution did help me with this problem! Although, since I could see myself using prompts like this fairly often, having some sort of "function" I could call would be useful.